# onesignal/onesignal.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, cocoapods

- Xcode version 7.3.1 and i have developer apple id

hi , i have strange problem to work and debug my project

The Error says : onesignal/onesignal.h file not found

i install and update pod without any error or problem through Console ,

i attach some screenshot that show error better

[image1](https://s32.postimg.org/404t0i9g5/fix3.jpg)

[image2](https://s32.postimg.org/6gdf6cf11/fix2.jpg)

where is the problem ? why i have not onesignal.h file after install it , and how can i fix this ?

please help me i stuck in this for a few weeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update to onesignal 2.0 with the command `pod repo update`

Answer (score 11):

```
cd platforms/ios

pod repo update

pod install
```

explanation: you need to navigate in to the ios platform directory where the .podfile exists, and then run the commands "pod repo update" and then "pod install"

Comment: Works like a charm with copy & paste in terminal

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**: I faced this again at an update from 3.0.7 (or later)

I fixed it with the following steps:

1. **Adding a *notification extension*** as described in the `react-native-onesignal` docs.
2. **Remove the old imports** and code from `AppDelegate.m`

**Removed lines**:

```
#import <OneSignal/OneSignal.h>
....
 (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
  if([self pushAvailable]) {
    [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
    [RCTOneSignal didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
 }
}
```

All the steps are described here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-onesignal#add-notification-service-extension

**Old answer**

For react-native-onesignal versions <= 3.0.7

1. Add OneSignal.framework that is in
   ../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios/Frameworks/OneSignal.framework
   in YourProject > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries
2. Add "$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios/Frameworks" in
   YourProject > Build Settings > Framework Search Paths

Run clean build before build.

Sources:

https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/19
https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/18

Answer (score -2):

You should remove

> **use_frameworks!**

from **ios/Podfile**

That will be work for me :)