# `RCTOneSignal.h file not found` build error OneSignal Library

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Xcode version 8.2.1

I can't run my project made in react native (Version 0.41.2). It's always popping me the same error:

Here's a
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckW7d.png)

- I've already tried this: [onesignal/onesignal.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231894/onesignal-onesignal-h-file-not-found)
- https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/127

I'm trying to add push notifications with onesignal on IOS, hope you can tell me what's the issue here.

Comment: What version of onesignal are you using?

Comment: the lastest version, 3.0

Comment: Have you tried [Setting up the Search Paths](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal#adding-search-paths)?

Comment: @max23_ yes, of course, still same result

Answer (score 0):

try to change #import "RCTOneSignal.h" with `#import <RCTOneSignal.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following to your target Header Search Paths under Build Settings on your XCode workspace:
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios/RCTOneSignal

also make sure libRCTOneSignal.a present in Link library with banary if not drag it from RCTonesignal.xcodeproj

you can take reference from below link
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking